# Show progress Bar when loading image with Glide in DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-glide

I am trying to learn `DataBinding` and stuck with one problem . I am not able to show Progress during loading the image with GLide . Below is my code .

```
 @BindingAdapter("android:src")
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String url){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
    Glide.with(view).load(url).into(view);
}


   @BindingAdapter({"android:src","progressBar"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String url, ProgressBar progressBar){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
        Glide.with(view).load(url)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(view);
}
```

And i am calling it as :

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater lp = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
    ItemImageSliderBinding itemBinding = ItemImageSliderBinding.inflate(lp, container, false);
    container.addView(itemBinding.getRoot());
    itemBinding.setImageUrl(images.get(position));
    itemBinding.executePendingBindings();
    return itemBinding.getRoot();
}
```

As you can see there is two overloaded method `loadImage` But i want to use 2nd one to show progress . How can i do that . May be there is some other elegant way to do this. But i can not figure out what is it. Currently my layout looks like below.

```
<layout>
<data>
    <variable
        name="imageUrl"
        type="String" />
</data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@{imageUrl}" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressImageSlider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can i bind `ProgressBar` with `BindingAdapter` to load images ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want using 2nd method:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:progressBar="@{progressImageSlider}"
        android:src="@{imageUrl}" />
```

But I think you should using placeholder in this case, please see my example

```
@BindingAdapter(value = { "android:src", "placeholder" }, requireAll = false)
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String url, Drawable placeHolder) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
        Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(url).placeholder(placeHolder).into(view);
    }
}
```

And call it in your xml

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:placeholder="@{@drawable/your_place_holder}"
        android:src="@{imageUrl}" />
```

hope this helps !

Comment: Thx. Yeah but whats the better way to doing it . Forget my 2nd Method .

Comment: I think you should'n using loading view, just using placeholder instead. Anw, I think its best solution if you want using loading view with data binding :)

Comment: Yeah i think so . Thx . Can you provide an example how do i code for it ?